# Having trouble using promises in jQuery/JavaScript. Script doesn't seem to wait

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, particles

I'm programming a Particle Photon (like an Arduino). I'm trying to call a variable from it and then use that variable to add a .css class to a div.

The problem is that the variable keeps coming back as

```
undefined
```

on the initial call. However, if I call it again a couple of seconds later, it works fine.

This is the API call from Particle:

```
 particle.getVariable({ deviceId: 'DEVICE_ID', name: 'temp', auth: token }).then(function(data) {
  console.log('Device variable retrieved successfully:', data);
}, function(err) {
  console.log('An error occurred while getting attrs:', err);
});
```

Here is my version of it:

```
function getVariable(varName) { 
particle.getVariable({ deviceId: device_ID, name: varName, auth: accessToken }).then(function(data) {
    return data.body.result;
    }, function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred while getting variable:', err);
});
}
```

I'd like to be able to work with this like

```
$(".class").addClass(getVariable("var")
```

I'm pretty new to jQuery and Javascript, but I've been doing a ton of reading on callbacks and promises and getting nowhere. Any idea how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues here.

1. Your `getVariable()` function needs to return the promise from `particle.getVariable()`.  That will allow the caller of `getVariable()` to use `.then()` on the returned result to get the asynchronous result.
2. Promises do not magically make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.  So, your `getVariable()` function is still asynchronous because it relies on the result of `particle.getVariable()` which is asynchronous.  So, you cannot return the result directly.  Instead, you should make it return a promise and the caller of that function can use `.then()` to retrieve the async result.
3. Since `getVariable()` will be asynchronous, you will need to use `getVariable(...)`.then(...) to get access to the async result.

Change to this:

```
function getVariable(varName) {
    return particle.getVariable({
        deviceId: device_ID,
        name: varName,
        auth: accessToken
    }).then(function (data) {
        return data.body.result;    // this becomes the fulfilled value of the promise
    }, function (err) {
        console.log('An error occurred while getting variable:', err);
        throw err;                  // rethrow error so it will propagate
    });
}

getVariable("var").then(function (result) {
    $(".class").addClass(result);
}, function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

For a lot more description of returning asynchronous values, you can see this: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323)

Comment: Oh my gosh. Thank you so much! I'd played with variations of your first section of code, but never thought to use a promise for the second section. Ugh. 

Is there any way to have it work at all with something like `$(".class").addClass(getVariable("var")`? Your solution works, but just hoping to simplify. Either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: @syndac - Nope, the result is async.  You can't return the result directly from `getVariable()`.

Comment: No problem. Thanks again for the help!